# How to catch LoadLibrary exception of "Bad Image"

Tags: c#, exception, winapi, try-catch, badimageformatexception

When I am trying to load a binary file with a magic start of "DCS" instead of the common "MZ", it fails with an error:

> C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_wcf-system.identitymodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.19041.1_none_e690fdc7d17e3f70\System.IdentityModel.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administator or the software vendor for support. Error status: 0xc000012f.

Even when I added `try...catch`:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern SafeLoadLibraryHandle LoadLibraryEx(string name, IntPtr reserved, LoadLibraryFlags flags);

public enum LoadLibraryFlags
{
    DontResolveDllReferences = 0x00000001,
}

...

string name = @"C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_wcf-system.identitymodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.19041.1_none_e690fdc7d17e3f70\System.IdentityModel.dll";  

SafeLoadLibraryHandle ret = null;
try
{
   ret = Win32NativeMethods.LoadLibraryEx(name, IntPtr.Zero, flags);
}
catch (Exception)
{

    //throw;
}
```

My current workaround is to check if the image starts with "MZ", if not, ignore it.
But I thought to check if someone knows a better way to handle it.

Comment: How do you even get to the point of loading arbitrary binaries of unknown providence as libraries into your own process? I'd suggest something has probably gone wrong with this plan well before the `LoadLibrary` step.

Comment: The binary is a standard DLL. My application running over files with extension EXE and DLL. It needs to load them in order to search some details inside them. There is no wrong step from my point.

Comment: It's not possible to catch this from inside the same function, because the Jitter is failing, so the `catch` isn't even compiled. You need to catch it from outside the function that calls it. You also need to force it not to inline that method

Comment: Don't use that flag, load as a datafile. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050214-00/?p=36463